# 4D Duoprisms based on nonconvex polygons

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes

A *[duoprism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duoprism)* is a polytope
that can be expressed as the Cartesian product of two polytopes (each of dimension $\ge 2$).
Four-dimensional duoprisms in particular have been studied: 
$$P \times Q = \{ (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \;\mid\; (x_1,x_2) \in P,\; (x_3,x_4) \in Q \} \;,$$
where $P$ and $Q$ are $2$-dimensional polygons.

All the literature I've seen assumes $P$ and $Q$ are convex polygons. For example,
here is a net for the product of a square and a regular hexagon:

---

[image: SquareHexagon]

               

<sup>(Image from [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duoprism#Nets).)</sup>

---

> ***Q***. Does anyone know of any investigations or uses of duoprisms
>   in which either or both of $P$ and $Q$ are nonconvex polygons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some information about the product of two pentagrams [here](http://bendwavy.org/klitzing/incmats/stardip.htm)

---

[image: StarStar]

---

Comment: Thanks, Kristal! (I added an image from the link you provided.)

Answer (score 1):

The [great duoantiprism](https://polytope.miraheze.org/wiki/Great_duoantiprism) can be constructed using a compound of two pentagonal-pentagrammic duoprisms by inserting additional edges, or by alternating a decagonal-decagrammic duoprism.